# pgfopts: arguments with spaces don't play well with babel

Tags: pdflatex

If I define a new package like this

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myPlanning}[2022/07/16 my Planning class]
\LoadClass[french]{article}

\RequirePackage{pgfopts}
\pgfkeys{
  /myOrg/.cd,
  lang/.initial        = english                       , lang/.store        in = \myOrg@lang,
  title/.initial       = title                         , title/.store       in = \myOrg@title,
}
\ProcessPgfOptions{/myOrg}

\RequirePackage[\myOrg@lang]{babel}
```

and I try to compile this document

```
\documentclass[lang=french,title={truc bidul}]{myPlanning}
\begin{document}
some text here
\end{document}
```

I get the following error:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./Test.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-01-21>
(/home/hylkema/texmf/tex/latex/local/Org/myPlanning.cls
Document Class: myPlanning 2022/07/16 my Planning class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgfopts/pgfopts.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.t
ex))))) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-french/french.ldf)

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.4261     \ifin@\edef\bbl@tempc{\bbl@tempb}\fi}
                                                
?
```

However, if I compile this (No spaces in the title argument):

```
\documentclass[lang=french,title=truc]{myPlanning}
\begin{document}
some text here
\end{document}
```

It compiles fine with no errors.

What's more, the first document with spaces in the title argument compiles fine if I remove the `\RequirePackage[\myOrg@lang]{babel}` line from the package definition.

Is this a known problem and is there a solution ?

Thanks for your help,

Jouke

Comment: The spaces are not the problem, the `{}`, which you need for the spaces, are the problem. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/322217/36296

Comment: I figured as much. So there is no easy solution to this except using ~ for spaces ?

Comment: You could look at other key-value packages....

Comment: Do you have suggestions?

Comment: I pinged somebody who might have some suggestions. Let's see if he would like to comment.

Comment: Apart from the "obvious" error you have another problem: your usage of `.initial` is wrong. If you use it before you defined the other handler (so before you used `.store in`) it'll do something completely different. If you don't set any of your options at `\documentclass` both your control sequences will be undefined if you try to use them. Correct would be to use `.store in` and afterwards set the option, like this: `title/.store in=\myOrg@title, title=<initial value>`.

Comment: My personal experience with class-options is pretty mixed. The "problem" is that the options given to `\documentclass` are global, hence affect all the packages. That might be good (you can just say `ngerman` in the class options and `babel` will pick it up as the language no matter whether it's loaded without any options), but often you want to specify stuff exactly for that class of yours.

Comment: If you're developing a new class I suggest you use either the new builtin mechanism of LaTeX for key=value options (`\DeclareKeys{lang .store = \myOrg@lang, title .store = \myOrg@title}`, then `\ProcessKeyOptions`), or `expkv-opt` (disclaimer: I'm the author of the latter; you'll most likely also want to use `expkv-def` if you decide to use `expkv-opt`).

Comment: As an additional bonus of using either the builtin mechanism or `expkv-opt` you'll not need braces anymore to protect spaces for those two (only commas and for the builtin option equals signs need special protection).

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** The underlying issue was fixed in upstream `babel` on 2022-11-24 and should be resolved in the next release.

---

The issue is not the key=value parser but a code block of `babel` that tries to detect whether the wrong language is loaded if it got both options from the `\documentclass` and options when the package was called. That being said, `pgfopts` isn't up-to-date with current LaTeX (there were substantial changes to the option-system about a year ago that `pgfopts` has not yet followed suit), the only solutions to key=value options that are compatible to my knowledge are the builtin mechanism and `expkv-opt`.

But as I said, neither will solve your issue. Using `main=\myOrg@lang` in the options of `babel` however will, as if you used the `main`-option the problematic code of `babel` will not be used. So if you change your class to the following the only (admittedly strange) warning regarding your options you'll get will be

```
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [french].
```

(but that stems from your strange usage of `\LoadClass`, in which `article` will add `french` to the unused options list though it isn't in the global options list, hence `babel` will not pick it up and remove it from said list).

```latex
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myPlanning}[2022/07/16 my Planning class]
\LoadClassWithOptions{article}

\RequirePackage{pgfopts}
\pgfkeys{
  /myOrg/.cd
  ,lang/.initial = english
  ,lang/.store in = \myOrg@lang
  ,title/.initial = title
  ,title/.store in = \myOrg@title,
}
\ProcessPgfOptions{/myOrg}

\RequirePackage[main=\myOrg@lang]{babel}
```

Comment: The LoadClass is my fault, I've been moving things around so much that I left this in. Of course, I called babel with \myOrg@lang.

Comment: However, you're right, the main= did the trick. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: @Jouke of course I'm right :) Jokes aside, I'm glad I could help.

Comment: @Jouke I've changed your `\LoadClass` to `\LoadClassWithOptions`, this way `article` will process all the options from the `\documentclass` call.